# Is it OK to dynamically generate sitemaps upon request?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, technical-seo

So I am building a custom website that will support multiple languages through different domains, I.E. `example.com`, `example.nl`, etc. Now I am having trouble with how I should generate the sitemap for these sites. Without going into too much technical details of the site, these are my options:

1. **Dynamically generate a sitemap upon request to `example.com/sitemap.xml`**: This can be an option where there won't actually be a sitemap.xml file generated. Only when someone goes to the `/sitemap.xml` url, it will be generated 'on the fly' based on their locale. Will this be OK in the eyes of Google?
2. **Generate a sitemap.xml file for every locale I support**: Another way could be generating a `sitemap_en.xml`, `sitemap_nl.xml` file for every supported locale. I could then serve these files based on the current locale of the website. So when a user is on `example.com`, I could serve the `sitemap_en.xml` file when a request is made to `/sitemap.xml`.

Will it matter what option I choose? The sites will rely heavily on SEO, so it is my primary concern I don't make any mistakes with this.